# trolleys with exchangeable wheels

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, damaged-luggage

Hello dear travel community! I guess this is a common question around here, as I am almost certain traveling experts are generally looking specifically for what I am seeking after.

Both my parter's and my own trolley / handbaggage / carry-on luggage broke down due to wheel failure. I perused the internet search for this, but came up almost empty. I am looking for a piece of luggage with exchangeable wheels. Specifically, any kind of wheels that can be bought anywhere in the world at the next semi-specialized shop selling some standard kind of wheels, let's say "wheels that would normally be found on inline skates".

Use case: I buy a carry-on luggage, guarantee expires, I go about my business, travelling some places, after 5 years, one of the wheels brakes in some way, I contact the company about replacing the wheels, company says

> Unfortunately, we have to inform you that the desired spare parts are
>   no longer available. As we would like to count you among our loyal
>   customers, we will give you a discount voucher of 15% on your next
>   purchase!

Frustration sets in!

Alternative outcome: company says

> Hey look, we just use inline skate wheels on our products. Your
>   guarantee has expired, so we won't provide free new wheels, but you
>   can buy them pretty much anywhere and fit 'em on yourself easily. Have
>   a nice day!

I am looking for the alternative outcome. Does anyone know how to get to it?

---

Apparently the "Osprey Sojourn" features exchangeable wheels, but I didn't find the information whether the wheels can be exchanged by some standard wheels or if they would require me to buy the replacement wheels from Osprey. Here's a link to what they look like:

https://www.hecktictravels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/osprey-wheels.jpg

The bag is pretty elaborate and wheighs 4 kg (which seems to be a normal weight for carry-ons), but i guess lighter should be possible without losing too much product-/manufacturing quality. I am looking for a piece of luggage that could be used for many years (if that wasn't clear, yet).

Comment: Five years? Wow, the wheels on my four-wheel trolleys lasted only about two!

Answer (score 2):

A good luggage repair shop can often work magic, including replacement wheels that may not be original, but will fit. Sometimes people will even [replace the wheels with inline skate wheels](https://lifehacker.com/switch-your-luggage-to-inline-skate-wheels-for-better-d-1788664054) in advance for more durability. (Note that this doesn't usually work with the "spinner" style bags, which usually have much more fragile wheels.) Before getting a whole new bag, it's worth seeing what a repair shop can do.

If you travel often enough for broken luggage to be a considerable problem, it likely makes sense to invest in high quality luggage with a long warranty. Good luggage manufacturers sell wheel/axle kits (see, for example, parts options for [Travelpro](https://help.travelpro.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007402648-Travelpro-Parts-Catalogs)), so you might pick some parts up in advance so you're not caught short if they're no longer available in the future. Briggs and Riley bags aren't cheap, but have [parts kits](https://www.briggs-riley.com/collections/self-repair-kits) for wheels available for a nominal fee in addition to the regular repair options. Red Oxx doesn't make bags with wheels, but has a very strong [lifetime warranty](https://help.redoxx.com/article/6-our-warranty).

Choosing a very common model, or even one of the models typically [used by flight crew](https://thewirecutter.com/blog/is-flight-crew-luggage-worth-buying/) will help ensure the availability of repair options in the future.

Comment: I'll wait to see what other answers might emerge, but this is a very good answer already!